# Complex and Quaternionic Matrices(Book)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, matrix-calculus, quaternions

I'm looking for a book on complex and quaternionic matrices and on the links between them and the real matrices.
I'm reading the book Matrix grops for undergradtautes(K.Tapp) but I'm looking for another text that goes deeper into these topics.
Do you have any hints?
Thanks.

Comment: Many books on linear algebra treat complex as the main field of elements. Quaternions I don't know so many though. But you can treat them as block matrices with 4x4 real matrices as elements.

Comment: For the relationship between complex and quaternionic matrices, there's Terry Loring's paper "Factorization of matrices of quaternions" (https://doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2012.08.006). It's important to bear in mind that linear algebra over a division ring has quite a few difficulties due to noncommutativity.